What are the specific differences between these two notations of supercell denoted by (√3×√3)R30∘ and (√3×√3)?
I am studying the super-cell structures in crystallography and came across two different notations:
(√3×√3)R30∘ and (√3×√3). I would like to understand whether these two notations represent the same super-cell or if they denote different structures. If they are different, could you please explain the differences between them? Specifically, I am interested in how the rotational aspect in the first notation affects the overall structure compared to the second notation.

You can read about Wood's notation here

Thank you @Shaun Han

To the best of my knowledge these refer to the same thing in a FCC system.  This is a short answer, but the rotation shown just is to help someone who wants to make the same cell.
In ASE you can make this by using the following function.
ase.build.fcc111_root("Pt", 3, (1, 1, 4))
You will see its a 30 degree rotation along the x axis away from the original x axis of a fcc111 cell.  I believe that technically any rotation of 30+60n degrees should be valid, but they are all equivalent due to the hexagonal symmetry.

Thank you @Tristan Maxson
